# how to go from JSP page to static page in spring MVC as I am getting error

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/pages/**" location="/WEB-INF/pages/" cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

getting error

> The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spring-config XML file that includes your `<mvc:resources>` tag should include the mvc namespace like this:

```
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">
```

Note: sometimes an exception like this is raised because the version number is included in the namespace, so alternatively try this way:

```
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

Also you need to have the `spring-webmvc` jar file included in your project or within your `pom.xml` if you are working with ***Maven*** and dependencies
(the version number is important and you should ensure that all other `org.springframework` jars/dependencies you use in your project match-up with this version number)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```